# Magento Add Shipping Tax to Tax Breakdown And Grand Total

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I'm using Magento and I am having a problem with the totals being displayed.

At the moment I have this:

```
Subtotal: £10.00
Shipping & Handling: £5.00
Tax (at the moment just using 20% of Subtotal) (20%):£2.00
Grand Total: £17.00
```

So It should look like:

```
Subtotal: £10.00
Shipping & Handling: £5.00
Tax (need it to be 20% of subtotal AND 20% of shipping & Handling) (20%):£3.00
Grand Total: £18.00
```

As you can see the Tax has gone from £2.00 to £3.00 as I need it to take 20% of the Shipping & Handling fee as well as 20% of the subtotal fee?

Comment: What version on Magento are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Tax Classes and change the `Tax Class for Shipping` drop down to `Shipping` and re-check your totals.

Comment: I have tried this but it has made no differnece to the totals? Any ideas?

Comment: The other things to look at would be in Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Calculation Settings.  Try toggling those settings.

Comment: None of those settings are making a difference I can show the shipping price on two lines one including Tax and one excluding Tax but the price with the Including Tax is not adding to the Tax Line itself or the Grand Total no matter what could it be a template problem?

Comment: Check your Tax rules under Admin -> Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules.  Do you have a tax rule that matches the tax setting of the product?

Comment: I have a Tax Rule set up with Customer Tax Class - "Retail Customer" Is this correct. I have Product Tax Class - with BOTH "Taxable Goods and Shipping" selected and Tax rate - "UK" selected?

Comment: You have your products all set to this tax class as well?

Comment: Yes I have these set up as well its soo weird can't figure it out

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way to do this would be to override the cart/totals.phtml template and use `$this->getTotals()` from the totals block and manually display the totals you want.

If you want a cleaner and more proper way of doing this, then the templates under the tax folder control how those things are rendered. Tax specifically has two blocks that use the template, one for the cart and one for the checkout. I cant remember their exact names atm. If you want to add this functionality into the block then override both blocks. If you would rather do it in the template then remember that you have access to all blocks that are going to render a page at template time. You can say `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('block.name');` I am not sure if the shipping total block will have the info you are looking for at that moment since it may be dynamically created by the cart totals block. If thats the case, then you will have to first get the totals block `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('cart.totals.block.name')` and call getTotals() on it. Then you can get 20% of whatever the shipping total has.

Comment: Seanbreeden has a better answer. Ive never used that setting but it looks like it does as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `Tax Class for Shipping` setting to `Taxable Goods`. Then as long as all of your products are set in the `Taxable Goods` tax class, the tax will include tax on the shipping charge.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to going to `System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Tax Classes`
and changing the `Tax Class for Shipping` drop down to `Shipping`
as suggested by seanbreeden,
you should also ensure that there is no `Tax Rule` applied on the `Shipping` `Tax Class`.

For this, go to `Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules` and filter by the correct `Customer Tax Class` and `Product Tax Class` = `Shipping`.

If there are rules found, click them one by one, and you will see which rate is applied on the `Shipping`. If you want to turn off the tax on shipping, you should remove the `Shipping` from all the `Tax Rules` that you have found.