# How do I include shipping tax in the grand total in Magento 1.7 checkout?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, checkout

Currently, under "Order Review" in Checkout, it lists the following:

- subtotal: $44.00
- shipping & handling cost: $0.00
- tax: $4.18
- grand total: $44.00

The problem is that the grand total does not include the tax amount (such that the grand total becomes $48.18

I have tried to solve this on the System/Config/Sales/Tax page in Magento 1.7, but no matter what configurations I change, I have not yet succeeded in making the grand total include the tax.

Note: the tax is based on where the order is shipped to (e.g. the company is based in Washington State, so there is a WA State shipping tax that is applied to the order)

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449629/magento-add-shipping-tax-to-tax-breakdown-and-grand-total) appears similar.

Answer (score 1):

Login to Admin go to

> System --> Configuration --> Sales --> Tax --> Shopping Cart Display Settings --> Include Tax In Grand Total --> Set to Yes --> Save Config"

as well set same setting to ' Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings'